# CloudError: Endpoint (observeMySession) responded with an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Node version: 20.5.0

Sails version (sails): 1.5.7

ORM hook version (sails-hook-orm): 4.0.0

Sockets hook version (sails-hook-sockets): 2.0.0

Organics hook version (sails-hook-organics): 2.0.0

Grunt hook version (sails-hook-grunt): 5.0

First install according to "get-started" and created "Web App"

Signed up with email address and when I try login I am facing this error.

"CloudError: Endpoint (observeMySession) responded with an error (or the request failed)."

```
Uncaught (in promise) CloudError: Endpoint (observeMySession) responded with an errorv(or the request failed).
   exec http://localhost:1337/dependencies/cloud.js:649
   _promise http://localhost:1337/dependencies/cloud.js:612
   toPromise http://localhost:1337/dependencies/cloud.js:610
   then http://localhost:1337/dependencies/cloud.js:592

cloud.js:649:33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was addressed and fixed in sails v1.5.8.
See here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/7297#issuecomment-1703316425

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue when creating a new app with boilerplate. Tried another Sails app e.g. https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration and that runs without problems. Problem only on client side.

```
account-notification-banner.component.js:55 Uncaught (in promise) CloudError: Endpoint (`observeMySession`) responded with an error (or the request failed).
at Object.exec (http://localhost:1337/dependencies/cloud.js:649:33)
at http://localhost:1337/dependencies/cloud.js:612:26
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.toPromise (http://localhost:1337/dependencies/cloud.js:610:24)
at Object.then (http://localhost:1337/dependencies/cloud.js:592:36)

Error Summary:
(see `.responseInfo` for more details)
·-------------·----------------------------------------·
|    Protocol | ws(s)://   (io.socket)
|     Address | POST http://localhost:1337/api/v1/observe-my-session
|        Exit | error
| Status Code | 403
·-------------·----------------------------------------·

Response Body:
Forbidden
```

Tried turning CSRF false in `config/security.js` but it didn't make any difference.